# Unable to access Azure blob with custom domain

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have images in Azure blob storage which I can access publicly at a URL such as:

https://app.blob.core.windows.net/images/share-img.png

I have added a custom (sub) domain `storage.mydomain.net` in the Storage Account Portal and verified it using the CNAME method and I try accessing the image with the custom domain URL such as:

http://storage.mydomain.net/images/share-img.png

And I get the following 404 message

```
The requested content does not exist.
HttpStatusCode: 404
ErrorCode: WebContentNotFound
RequestId : 5ce62ecb-e01e-0050-1941-039626000000
TimeStamp : 2019-05-05T12:56:11.3927925Z
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Things of note:

- I don't think I need to add a CDN for this as I'm not going to serve
  images over HTTPS (yet).
- I have disabled secure transfer in the Portal configuration section.
- The URLs above are just for example

Comment: Process wise it looks like you did everything right. Will it be possible for you to share the actual URL (both storage and custom domain)?

Comment: Are the resources available for anonymous users and loading on the https://app.blob.core.windows.net/images/share-img.png path?  Just making sure that the default of private which caries the need for a SAS does not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> verified it using the CNAME method

How did you verified it?

You can use dns [lookup tool](https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx) to check if your sub domain works.
[image]

Here are all my steps to make it work.

1.I bought the domain from Azure. So I just added a CNAME for the storage endpoint.

[image]

2.Then add the custom domain to storage.
[image]